# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: table "table-name" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-migrations, heroku-postgres

I was messing with my database, creating and deleting tables. I deleted few migration files after pushing them to heroku. Previously I created a table 'moms'. Later I wanted to rename it, so I deleted 'moms' and created new table 'minutes_of_meetings'. I did $rake db:migrate and everything was done successfully and my app is running perfectly on localhost.

After pushing it to heroku, when I did $heroku run rake db:migrate, it generated the following log:

```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  Migrating to DropMoms (20150823142852)
  (0.6ms)  BEGIN
             == 20150823142852 DropMoms: migrating =========================================
                 -- drop_table(:moms)
             (0.9ms)  DROP TABLE "moms"
             PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "moms" does not exist
             : DROP TABLE "moms"
             (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
             rake aborted!
             StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

                                                                                     PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "moms" does not exist
             : DROP TABLE "moms"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
      /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
```

I created a new table 'moms' in heroku so that it can be deleted when migration runs. I did this:

```
$ heroku run Ruby console for rails-app-name >> ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table :moms
```

I also created a migration to create table 'moms'. But still the error persists.

EDIT:

This is my CreateMoms migration file:

```
class CreateMoms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :moms do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamp null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When I run heroku run rake db:migrate:up

```
Running `rake db:migrate:up` attached to terminal... up, run.1729
rake aborted!
VERSION is required
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:78:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:up
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.41.3 update available.
```

On heroku run rake db:migrate:down

```
Running `rake db:migrate:down` attached to terminal... up, run.6389
rake aborted!
VERSION is required - To go down one migration, run db:rollback
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:down
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.41.3 update available.
```

Comment: can you show the migration file? Migration should always be written in such a way that the reverse migration works too.

Comment: what happens if you try: `heroku run rake db:migrate:up` and `heroku run rake db:migrate:down`?

Comment: do you still have `moms` table in your schema on heroku?

Comment: I've updated the log file generated by heroku run rake db:migrate:up and down. And yes I have moms in my table

Comment: Try: `heroku run rake db:schema:load`  and then try running the migration again: `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: You just saved my day! Thanks. Please post it as an answer. Btw what was the fault and what db:schema:load did?

Comment: You are most welcome :)
`rake db:schema:load` just loads the `schema.rb` file into the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Caution

`rake db:schema:load` will wipe away all of your data from the heroku database. Please make sure you have your data backup on heroku. If you already don't have backup of your heroku database, you can easily do so by using [Heroku PGBackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups)

Looks like your `schema` is messed up. Just load the schema to the database using `rake db:schema:load` and then run the migration again:

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Data in my app has been removed. How can I get it back?

Comment: You can export/import data using heroku PG Backups. Instructions are here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: I had a huge amount of data and I don't remember I've ever created a backup.. Is there any way to undo db:schema:load? :(

Comment: Or, you can load the seed data using: `heroku run rake db:seed`

Comment: oh, you did not have a backup? :(

Comment: What should I do now? :(

Comment: I am afraid, we can't undo `db:schema:load` .
My mistake, I should have asked before if you have a databack. My understanding as your app is on heroku, you mush have tdata backup with the PG Backups

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87707/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-fhaider).