# Rails 4 Active Record Testing suite wants to truncate a table that doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

#### Background

Hey, I'm attempting to get a broken testing suite for my Rails 4 application working.

I had a table called `task_comments` back somewhere in the history of the application and there were some changes that called for the table to be deleted. Which it is, just fine.

Rails:    4.2.11.3 
Ruby:     2.3 
Postgres: 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1)

#### The Problem

The problem seems to be something with how ActiveRecord works with Postgres when *wiping the testing database* and it's thinking `task_comments` is supposed to still be in the application.

The problem comes when I try to run a test file that looks like this:

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class ClientTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    puts "asserting via test case"
    assert true
  end
end
```

I'm getting this issue:

```bash
$ rake test test/unit/client_test.rb

/usr/local/bundle/gems/mailman-rails-0.0.3/lib/mailman-rails/tasks/mailman.rake
Run options: --seed 29404

1) Error:
ClientTest#test_the_truth:
RuntimeError: Wrapped undumpable exception for: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "task_comments" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "task_comments"
```

#### Work Done

What I've tried to correct the issue:

```bash
 RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop;        # Removing the entire database
 RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create;      # Initializing the database
 RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load; # Reloading the db:schema
 RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate      # Repoplulating database structure
```

Also note that when reloading the schema, the table `task_comments` is not loaded in, and it is NOT in `schema.rb`, so I'm kind of stuck here in running a testing suite.

Similar issue that doesn't solve the problem: [PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: table "table-name" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168182/pgundefinedtable-error-table-table-name-does-not-exist)

Comment: Probably you have somewhere `task_comments` or `TaskComment`. Grep it

Comment: @mechnicov This is true, I had task_comments in a testing fixture.  It wasn't a part of the file text, but it was resolving the fixture as a table.  Which there is no way to derive that from the error message, I just had to get lucky...which I did.